# Data is array of objects passed to action through AJAX

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core

Here I can pass data as an array of objects to the controller through AJAX but the value I got on the controller side is null.

```
var newData  = [{Code:"FT",Id:1:Year:2005,TypeId:1,Value:20},
                {Code:"FR",Id:2:Year:2006,TYpeId:3,Value:40},
                {Code:"FY",Id:3:Year:2007,TYpeId:5,Value:50}]


$.ajax({
    url: "api/FG/cretejson",
    type: 'POST',
   contentType: "application/json",
   data: JSON.stringify({ extraParams: newData }),
   success: function (data) {
       var result = result;
   }
});

public JsonResult cretejson([FromBody]List<rev> extraParams)
{
    try
    {

        return Json(new { Result = "OK", Options = extraParams });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
    }
}
public class rev
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `TypeId` is an `int` in both the JSON and the c# model. Same with `Value`. Why is then `Year` an `int` in the c# model but a `string` in the JSON?

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify({ extraParams: newData })` This line will send a body like `extraParams={ YOUR JSON AS STRING}`. Can you please try sending by `data: newData`

Comment: camilo, By my mistake we can edit it models..

Comment: Camil, Please help me..

Comment: Oguz Ozgu, I try this way but not getting value.

Comment: Camil, any suggestions would you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX call:

```
 $.ajax({
       url: urlString,
       type: 'POST',
       data: sc,
       dataType: 'json',
       crossDomain: true,
       cache: false,
       success: function (data) { console.log(data); }
    });
```

Web API controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public string PostProducts([FromBody]List<SyncingControl> persons)
 {
    return persons.Count.ToString(); // 0, expected 3
 }
```